# mod_rewrite rule works on localhost but not on production server, due to presence of file extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got an htaccess file with about a dozen rules, all work fine on localhost. In fact, all work fine on my production server as well, the only issue is that I find myself having to modify the rules each time I move from localhost to production. The exact issue is that on localhost (XAMPP), the rule only works *without* the presence of the file extension (`.php` in my case) whereas on my production server, just the opposite is true.

#### Example

```
RewriteRule ^demopage.php/([0-9]+)/?$ /anotherpage.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

The above works on my production server, but **not** on localhost.

```
RewriteRule ^demopage/([0-9]+)/?$ /anotherpage.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

The above works on localhost, but **not** on my proudction server.

#### More about my setup

The production server is running with CentOs 6. I am using virtual hosts for the domains. Here are the configurations for my virtual host:

```
<Directory /var/my/directory/path/my.domain.com>
        Options -Indexes +Multiviews +FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The configuration on my localhost is a lot different, I don't have directory specific rules setup so it's hard for me to determine where the two setups differ. Also doesn't help that I'm fairly new to mod_rewrites. If there are some other details I'm forgetting just ask and I'll edit the question.

Comment: Try to remove the Multiviews option, this thing plays with file extensions.

Comment: I'll try that in just a few minutes. thank you. Curious though, again I'm new to this, will removing Multiviews possibly mess with other areas of the site? @regilero

Comment: No removing `Multiviews` shouldn't impact any rewrite rules.

Comment: @regilero If you get a minute, post an answer so I can accept. Seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I totally agree,  @regilero needs to convert comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the [Multiviews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) option, this thing plays with file extensions.

This is related to `mod_negociation` and activate default extension search (you ask for `foo` and `foo.html` and `foo.php` are tested).